# When debugging an application inside Eclipse, how to make it substitute an input argument path containing '~/' by the $HOME?

Tags: eclipse

I have an application that receives as input argument a path.

I realized that when debugging it inside Eclipse (Run->Run Configurations->Arguments), if I provide an input path containing "~/", it is not substituted by the home folder. 
In other words, my input argv[] variable will receive the "~/" instead of "$HOME/".

I understand that this functionality is provided by the shell, but I would like to know if it is possible to reproduce it inside Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

use ${env_var:HOME} instead of ~ in your command line args.